# Removing a key in a list of dictionary with if value condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Here's my sample data, I want to remove the keys with "N/A" values using python.

```
Data = [
  {
    "Area": "Los Angeles",
    "Idle": "N/A",
    "Downtime": "N/A",
    "Production": "N/A",
    "Total": "0.00 kWh",
    "Total_Cost": "$ 0.00",
    "Total_Idle_Cost": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Area": "Oklohoma",
    "Idle": "N/A",
    "Downtime": "N/A",
    "Production": "N/A",
    "Total": "0.00 kWh",
    "Total_Cost": "$ 0.00",
    "Total_Idle_Cost": "N/A"
  }]
```

The output i want, remove the keys with "N/A" value.

```
 Data = [
      {
        "Area": "Los Angeles",
        "Total": "0.00 kWh",
        "Total_Cost": "$ 0.00",
      },
      {
        "Area": "Oklohoma",
        "Total": "0.00 kWh",
        "Total_Cost": "$ 0.00",
      }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
Data = [{key: value for key, value in entry.items() if value != "N/A"} for entry in Data]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ! can you explain the functions used in this script?

Comment: Sure! The outer brackets, [], are a list comprehension which iterates through your list, Data. for each entry in the data (dicts) we iterate through the key-value pairs using entry.items(), which gives the key-value pairs as a list of tuples. We build a new dictionary using {} out of the entries for which the value isn't "N/A".

Comment: Well explained! i understand it now. Thanks for the help sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def returnNewDict(oldDict):
    newDict = {}
    for key, value in oldDict.items():
        if value != 'N/A':
            newDict[key] = value
    return newDict

newData = [returnNewDict(oldDict) for oldDict in Data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = [
  {
    "Area": "Los Angeles",
    "Idle": "N/A",
    "Downtime": "N/A",
    "Production": "N/A",
    "Total": "0.00 kWh",
    "Total_Cost": "$ 0.00",
    "Total_Idle_Cost": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Area": "Oklohoma",
    "Idle": "N/A",
    "Downtime": "N/A",
    "Production": "N/A",
    "Total": "0.00 kWh",
    "Total_Cost": "$ 0.00",
    "Total_Idle_Cost": "N/A"
  }]     

def NAremove1(d):
    if not isinstance(d,dict):
        return d if not isinstance(d,list) else list(map(NAremove1,d))
    return { k:NAremove1(v) for k,v in d.items() if v != 'N/A'}

print(NAremove1(Data)) 
 
"""
[{
'Area': 'Los Angeles', 
'Total': '0.00 kWh',
 'Total_Cost': '$ 0.00'}, 
 {'Area': 'Oklohoma', 
 'Total': '0.00 kWh', 
 'Total_Cost': '$ 0.00'}]

"""
```